# Can I add a dropdown menu in DOCUMENTS category without using div?

Tags: html, css

How I will add a dropdown menu only in documents category without using div? Is it possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Kenneth Abuel | Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>




<ul>
<li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="documents.html">Documents</a>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me!</a>
</ul>
</div>
</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>dropdown1</a></li>
        <li><a>dropdown2</a></li>
        <li><a>dropdown3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="documents.html">Documents</a>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me!</a>
</ul>
```

If you need acctual dropdown code, make a fiddle, will try to help!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried it it work. I thought you can't use dropdown without div, I'm newb in html and css. Now I am working on CSS

Comment: You can use whatever you like, until you are following basic rules. Read this: http://cssguidelin.es/
But learn by doing! And you will be fine :)
Could you accept my answer if it helped? Thanks.